# seting up some windows10 pro kiosks?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-10, kiosk

I have a few windows 10 PCs for student use. Previously, I had windows XP installed where I was using deepfreeze. Basically, students could use the pc, but if they encountered malicious software, rebooting would set the PC back to a clean image.  That worked great... But now we cant get that software, its both more expensive now, and we have budget issues.

I heard (read) that windows10 can boot into a Virtual Machine, and restore itself in minutes, to a clean image, either as a scheduled task, or as a process that occurs on reboot. Well, that sounds great, but I cant find any way to set that up.

Can someone point me to some detailed instructions on how to set up windows10 for some sort or kiosk mode, or so that Windows10 boots clean on each reboot?

We have windows10 Pro here. I'm not sure if kiosk mode is the right term. 
Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only option that I have found that is close to Kiosk mode for Windows 10. I'm borrowing this information from another site.  I hope this provides some options or spurs ideas.

How to edit the Registry to create a Kiosk:
http://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/feature/Windows-kiosk-mode-locks-down-PCs-but-note-workarounds

Click start and type regedit.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
A registry entry called "Shell" is configured to start Explorer.exe. This executable is the Windows desktop environment. The OS allows you to run your application in place of the Windows Explorer shell.
Once the app's EXE path is specified in the above registry key location and the next time a user logs on to the Windows PC, the OS runs the app rather than launching the Windows Explorer shell. Replacing Explorer.exe with a choice of application EXE to start when a user logs on to the computer is sometimes referred to as "kiosk mode."
To get Remote Desktop to open automatically for all users -  Edit the Shell entry under Winlogon andreplace it with %windir%\system32\mstsc.exe
•   Since the kiosk mode is configured per machine, you don't have control over which users can access which applications. For example, the configuration approach described above also applies to local administrator accounts.
•   Users with administrative rights can launch the Windows Registry Editor via Task Manager and modify the registry entry value to run any other application.
•   Users can switch to the desktop by pressing the ALT+ESC key combination.
•   Users can also close the application by pressing the ALT+F4 key combination.
•   Users can kill the application using Task Manager and launch Explorer.exe via Task Manager > Run, which in turn allows users to access the desktop.
If you wanted to completely lock down a workstation -- making sure, for example, that users do not use the ALT+CTRL+DEL key combination to kill an application -- you could configure various Group Policy settings to disable Task Manager, etc. However, this will not help in a complete lockdown of a workstation. A smart user could always break this functionality by using a number of techniques.